# Integrate $\int_0^{1/a} \frac {\sqrt{1-a^2 x^2}}{1-x^2} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given $a \in \mathbb {R}_{> 0}$ compute the integral
$$\int_0^{1/a} \frac {\sqrt{1-a^2 x^2}}{1-x^2} \mathrm{d}x.$$

After one or two substitutions I usually end up using the half tangent substitution, but this then forces me to perform a cumbersome partial fraction decomposition, and I want to avoid this.
Any suggestions for good substitutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the integral converges only for $a\ge 1$. Substitute $ax=\sin t$ to integrate

\begin{align}
&\quad\int_0^{1/a} \frac{\sqrt{1-a^2 x^2}}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=a\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2t}{a^2-\sin^2t}dt\\
&=a\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(1- \frac{\sec^2t}{\tan^2t+\frac{a^2}{a^2-1}}\right) dt\\
&=\frac\pi2 \left(a-{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)
\end{align}